# Can anybody tell me what am I missing? It's showing "Uncaught ReferenceError: func is not defined" when I am clicking the button

Tags: html

Can anybody tell me what am I missing? It's showing "Uncaught ReferenceError: func is not defined" when I am clicking the button.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My Admin</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main">
        <button onclick="func()">Click Me</button>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascipt">
        function func(){
            alert("called func");
        }
    </script>

</body>
```

Comment: you are trying to call a function that is not yet defined, simple as that. you are only defining it in a script block AFTER your button, move it before the button or to the head section.

Comment: @Banana that's not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You mistyped javascript...  see the `type` of the script

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>My Admin</title>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="main">
    <button onclick="func()">Click Me</button>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function func() {
      alert("called func");
    }
  </script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Typing Mistake . Replace "text/javascipt" to "text/javascript".